# XPath NodeList order (Java)

Tags: java, xpath, nodelist

I have the following XML structure.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root> 
  <header> 
    <row> 
      <column n="name" />
      <column n="age" />
      <column n="email" />
    </row> 
  </header>  
  <body> 
    <row> 
      <column>Foo</column>  
      <column>99</column>  
      <column>foo@test.com</column> 
    </row>  
  </body> 
</root>
```

I'm using the following XPath expression to get the header columns and likewise to get the body columns.

```
PathExpression headerExpr = xPath.compile("/root/header/row/column/@n");
NodeList headerColumns = (NodeList) headerExpr.evaluate(document, XPathConstants.NODESET);
PathExpression bodyExpr = xPath.compile("/root/body/row/column");
NodeList bodyColumns = (NodeList) bodyExpr.evaluate(document, XPathConstants.NODESET);
for (int i = 0; i < headerColumns.getLength(); i++) {
                System.out.println((Attr) headerColumns .item(i)).getValue() + ": " + bodyColumns.item(i).getTextContent());
        }
```

Can I assume that XPath will always return the header and body columns in the same order so that they will always match? Or can I even assume that the columns are always returned in document order?

Comment: Have you tested it? This sounds like a fairly obvious question, so there's probably documentation on it.

Comment: XPath traverses top down, so if you're asking whether or not you'll get back "name, age, email" instead of some random ordering you are correct.

Comment: I've tested it and it works, however I coulnd't find any documentation within 15min stating that XPath will return children in document order. So if you can point me to the spec that will be perfect

Comment: If you implementation of XPath behaves consistently then you can probably use the node order.

Comment: If I understand [this specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#data-model) correctly, the document order will dictate the order of elements. I am however not sure that that spec is current.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The document order is always preserved when using XPath, here's something official for your reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256090.aspx